# How to get a background image to work in CSS and HTML?

Tags: css, image, background, positioning, image-size

I'm sorry for a seemingly foolish question, but I really do need help with this.

I want to create a background image for my website. I made a 1920x1080 background image, and I want it to cover the background on my website. Here is the code a the moment:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif, Times New Roman;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666666
    background: #000000;
    background-image:url(images/background/webbackground.png);
}
```

When I look at the website after this block of code, it isnt positioned properly. I've tried some `background-size:` options but I haven't found anything that would work. I also want this background image to change depending on the resolution size of the viewer's monitor.

Can anyone give any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `background-size: cover;` on newer browsers.

Or follow a fixed position centering / scaling method like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

Example: http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/css-2.php

Reference: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: background-size: cover; causes it to become blocks on my page, my image turns into about 4 blocks, here is a picture http://gyazo.com/bfefc946c5c7b93a9d53869764e2f26f

Comment: I just found out it was because of my max-width: 960px;. I guess I have to throw that out the window! haha

Comment: Nice! Glad you found the culprit. I overlooked that in your original code. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

width:100%;
background-size:cover;